# How to covert the integer number in component.ts to float value using format printing in html template in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I Want to convert the integer value in float on html template in angular !

Here is the link, i want to convert that 10 as 10.00 , can anyone help me out with this !

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-driscoll-9jhjg?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure you have decimalPipe added as a provider, then you just need to modify the format string for the pipe to make it always 2 trailing decimals:

```
  <h1>{{ age | number: '1.2-2' }}</h1>
```

See [DecimalPipes](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)  for more info.
In this case, 2-2 means you want a minimum of 2 decimals and a maximum of 2.

and the import:

```
  providers: [DecimalPipe],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Decimal Number pipe in html file.

**.ts** File

```
randNumber = 10;
```

**.html** File

```
{{randNumber | number:'0.2'}}
```